# List minimum and maximum value in array

Tags: c++

I need to list down the minimum and maximum value from array. For example I have 10 arrays, so I need to list down the 5 minimum and 5 maximum from the array. I want make my program can do this.. example

{1.2, 3.5, 4.5, 8.9, 2.4, 6.5, 7.8, 3.3, 6.5, 9.5}
{1.2 < 3.5, 4.5 < 8.9, 2.4 < 6.5, 7.8 < 3.3, 6.5 < 9.5}

If the number is small then win
Win: 1.2 4.5 2.4 3.3 6.5
Lose: 3.5 8.9 6.5 7.8 9.5

I've already tried many loop style and boolean in code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //double arr[2] = {1.2, 3.5};
    double arr[10] = {1.2, 3.5, 4.5, 8.9, 2.4, 6.5, 7.8, 3.3, 6.5, 9.5};
    double min = arr[0];
    double max = arr[0];
    double Sdata[5] = {0};
    double Bdata[5] = {0};
    int counterMin = 0;
    int counterMax = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i<10; i++){

        if(arr[i]<max || arr[i]> max){
            max = arr[i];
            if(counterMax<5){
                Bdata[counterMax] = max;
                counterMax++;
            }
            max = arr[i+1];
        }

        if(arr[i]<min || arr[i]> min){
            //min = arr[i];
            if(counterMin<5){
                Sdata[counterMin] = min;
                counterMin++;
            }
            min = arr[i+1];
        }



    }

    //Output
    cout<<"Minimum: "<<endl;
    for(int w = 0; w<5; w++){
        cout<<Sdata[w]<<" ";
    }

    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Maximum: "<<endl;

    for(int j = 0; j<5; j++){
        cout<<Bdata[j]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}


Output from the program is:
Minimum:
1.2 4.5 2.4 7.8 6.5
Maximum:
3.5 8.9 6.5 3.3 9.5

I expect the output from the program is:
Minimum:
1.2 4.5 2.4 3.3 6.5
Maximum:
3.5 8.9 6.5 7.8 9.5
```

Comment: Could you please explain your problem more clearly? Your description is pretty hard to parse and doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: sort the array then print first 5 and last 5, use `std::sort`

Comment: Please spend some time in stating the question in a clear form.

Comment: 10 arrays, or 1 array with 10 elements?

Comment: Are you trying to partition the elements of an array into two other arrays such that, given each pair of consecutive elements, the lower number goes into the first and the bigger into the second?

Comment: I *think* you want the min and max of each pair of elements in the array?

Comment: I am sure once we can figure out what you really want to do, that this can be done with an STL algorithm call or two, and no need to write loops.

Comment: @iHowell, I'm so sorry. Actually I want get minimum and maximum like Shawn said. But I want list it down into 2 group which is minimum and maximum..

Comment: @Shawn yes. I need get minimum and maximum each pair. I don't want use sort library..

Comment: @Bob_ yeah, that what I want to do..

Comment: @JaironLanda -- If that's what you want to do, then the solution is *much* simpler than what you posted.  It is literally a two-line `for` loop.  So the question is, why is your loop doing so much, i.e. `counterMax` -- what is that for?  Is there something else that you're supposed to do?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I want group the number into 2 groups. Which is minimum and maximum, I want count it until 5 times. I expect I can get 5 minimum and 5 maximum.

Comment: You know that the element in the output arrays will be at position `i / 2` in the loop.  There  is no need for those counting variables.  And why are you starting your loop at 1?  It looks like you are using a "find the minimum/maximum" homework sample, and (erroneously) working from that sample.  That's the only plausible reason I see for you starting at 1.

Comment: Please note that array indices start from 0, not 1. You just need to compare `arr[i]` with `arr[i + 1]` and decide what goes into `low[i/2]` and `high[i/2]`. Then consider the next pair `i += 2`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `||` operator? That feels like a bug, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Bob__ i' m sorry I don't get it. Can you show me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is list the min/max pair of adjacent numbers, then the following is all that needs to be done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    double arr[10] = { 1.2, 3.5, 4.5, 8.9, 2.4, 6.5, 7.8, 3.3, 6.5, 9.5 };
    const int sz = (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])); // number of elements
    const int outsize = sz / 2; // number of elements in output array 
    double Sdata[outsize] = { 0 };
    double Bdata[outsize] = { 0 };

    // loop for each pair
    for (int i = 0; i < sz - 1; i += 2) 
    {
            // minimum in Sdata, maximum in Bdata
        Sdata[i / 2] = std::min(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
        Bdata[i / 2] = std::max(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
    }

    //Output
    std::cout << "Minimum: \n";
    for (int w = 0; w < 5; w++) {
        std::cout << Sdata[w] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Maximum: \n";

    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        std::cout << Bdata[j] << " ";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Minimum: 
1.2 4.5 2.4 3.3 6.5 
Maximum: 
3.5 8.9 6.5 7.8 9.5
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want. By the way, why we need to divide to 2?

Comment: It is possible to get the position of element for minimum and maximum?

Comment: You need to divide by 2 since the value of `i` in the loop is incremented by 2 on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you for explain, By the way, it is possible to get the position of minimum and maximum value?

Answer (score 1):

C++ actually offers algorithms that help you find the minimum and maximum elements in a container/array:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const double arr[] = {1.2, 3.5, 4.5, 8.9, 2.4, 6.5, 7.8, 3.3, 6.5, 9.5};
  auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
  std::cout << "Min: " << *min << "\n";
  std::cout << "Max: " << *max << "\n";
}
```

You can use [std::min_element()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element), [std::max_element()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) in case you only need one of them.

Comment: The question may be a little off, but as it turns out in the comment section, this is not what the OP originally intended.

Answer (score 1):

First of, as the question is tagged as C++, I think you should be better of just using `std::vector` instead of arrays.
Aside from that, if you'd want to sort the array *pair wise* you can use something like this.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> arr{1.2, 3.5, 4.5, 8.9, 2.4, 6.5, 7.8, 3.3, 6.5, 9.5};
    std::vector<double> maxs(arr.size()/2);
    std::vector<double> mins(arr.size()/2);
    double max, min;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < arr.size()/2; ++i)
    {
        min = arr[2*i];
        max = arr[2*i + 1];

        if (min > max) std::swap(min, max);

        maxs[i] = max;
        mins[i] = min;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is just a simple snippet, without error/bound checks etc...
You could also check if your original vector contains an even number of elements, and then go on accordingly.
If I didn't understand something correctly or made any mistakes, feel free to correct me!

Comment: Yes its working, but I more prefer array instead vector. Thanks

Comment: Yes its working, but I more prefer array instead vector. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `std::minmax_element`. It does not need to iterate twice over the array as a approach with `std::min_element` **and** `std::max_element` would need to.

Moreover, I suggest to use `std::array` instead of POD C array

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::array<double,10> arr {1.2, 3.5, 4.5, 8.9, 2.4, 6.5, 7.8, 3.3, 6.5, 9.5};
   const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
   std::cout << "min = " << *min << ", max = " << *max << '\n';
}
```